# How to show terminal/shell code snippets in Sphinx?

Tags: terminal, python-sphinx

Using Sphinx, I know you can show a code snippet by having something like:

```
.. code-block:: ruby.
  ${your ruby code goes here}
```

How can I show a code snippet of terminal or shell commands not related to any languages? I don't care if they are not highlighted properly syntax wise, I just want them show up in the doc as a piece of code other than normal text.

**Example**

```sh
$ ls -lsa . 
$ make file
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can indent the text you want to be written as code, and precede that with a double colon. For example:

```
Some body text explaining what's coming up::

    ls -lsa .
    make file
```

Or it also turns out you can get away without any text before, just using the double colons.  In the first case, one colon gets rendered, while for this case, just the code gets rendered.

```
::
    mkdir test
    cd !$
```

Then the commands will come out in a fixed-width font, and, depending on the style sheets you've chosen, highlighted as well (by default, highlighted with green background).

You can also inline-highlight with backticks, e.g. `` `ls -lsa .` ``.

Comment: As [wswld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349940/wswld) [notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317799/2809027), this lightweight approach is inadvisable unless also paired with a parser directive resembling `.. highlight:: console` at the head of your ReST document. Doing so informs the ReST parser (e.g., Sphinx) of the default language to be used for all code blocks lacking an explicit language. In this case, that should be `console` – the "language" associated with Bash shell one-liners intended to be run interactively. That said, explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 51):

```
.. code-block:: console
```

is meant for interactive sessions. Bash or sh didn't work for me.

( from http://build-me-the-docs-please.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Using_Sphinx/ShowingCodeExamplesInSphinx.html#pygments-lexers )

Comment: This is preferred over `bash` or `sh`, since it's a console/terminal that is being described, not a script. Be aware though that it doesn't handle long lines well.

Comment: If you're using sphinx-copybutton to have the copy-to-clipboard button, you need also to add *copybutton_exclude = '.linenos, .gp'* in conf.py so the prompt will not be copied to clipboard too.

Answer (score 34):

For Linux console commands you could use `bash` or `sh`:

```
.. code-block:: bash

   $ ls -lsa .
   $ make file
```

Highlighting wouldn't probably work right all the time, but at least you give it a chance.

You can also set the default highlighting in the beginning of the file if you use the @Bonlenfum way with double colons:

```
.. highlight:: sh
```

Comment: In this case, you should prefer `console` rather than `bash`, as in Marco Mariani's answer. `bash` might misinterpret console-specific syntax such as the $ / # in the beginning of a line